# jQuery: single mouseenter/mouseleave handler

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, event-delegation

I need to track mouseenter / mouseleave events for all elements on the page.

Intuitively written code for it was:

```
$(window).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target, e.type);
  // ...
});
```

But it fires mouseleave events every time mouseenter happens on child element, thus nullifying all benefits of mouseenter/mouseleave, i.e. it works like mouseover/mouseout.

Is there a way to handle this without attaching handlers directly to all elements?

And does this look like a jQuery bug? Because from what I know and from jQuery docs I've read it looks like the above code should work fine.

JSBin to play with: http://jsbin.com/axuluc/2/

**Edit:** this works as expected: http://jsbin.com/axuluc/9/

Comment: Do you mean you need to track for literally all elements? For example, every `<div>`, `<img>`, etc.?

Comment: It works just fine, but when the mouse enters a new element, it leaves another element, like you would expect!

Comment: You want to track mouseenter/leave for all elements, but it fires for every child element... Isn't that what you want? Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? the jsbin seems to work as expected for me, in Chrome anyway.

Comment: I don't want "mouseleave" to be triggered when I move from an elements to its child. This is the whole thing about "mouseenter/mouseleave" events.

Comment: Then just remove the `mouseleave` part ?

Comment: @adeneo I want to track mouseleave. But I want it to behave like mouseleave, i.e. I don't want it triggered when I move from element to its children. I only want it to be triggered when I really move mouse outside the element.

Comment: It works as I want it to work if I replace "window" with "*", but it cancels the benefit of delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Well child elements are included in **all** definition, aren't they?

Give the desired elements a class if possible like `class="mouse_active"` 
or use proper selector.

Then...

```
$(window).on('mouseenter mouseleave','.mouse_active', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target, e.type);
  // ...
});
```

and you still attach a single handler

Comment: not possible. I can not modify the DOM (imagine a browser plugin, for example)

Comment: Any info about the structure of the document? Perhaps there can be found some proper selecting logic

Comment: Do you target only top level elements?

Comment: No, I need to target every single element in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it:

```
$(window).hover(
   function(){
      // mouse enter function...
   },
   function(){
      // mouse leave function...
   }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: This is **not** the right way to do it, it's exactly the same as the OP's code, as hover() is just a jQuery shortcut for mouseenter and mouseleave ?